# Getting the text of a particular line on UITextView

Tags: ios, text, uitextview, line

Ultimately, I would like to know the position of the last character in a UITextView.  I was able to find out the y position by using the following:

> CGSize size = [textView.text
>                   sizeWithFont:textView.font
>                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width-16, 10000)
>                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];

However in order to get the x position I need to get the text from the last line in the textview.  I tried removing a character at a time from textView.text until size.height changes to achieve that effect, but I realize that does not always equal to what I want when linebreak is taken into consideration.

Any suggestions anyone?  I've been spending a whole day trying to figure this one out...

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution by using caretRectForPosition to get the pixel position of the cursor in the textview.

```
// move cursor to the end of the text
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange([textView.text length], 0);
CGPoint cursorPosition = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can evaluate the text size in a uitextview or uitextfield like this 

    `UIFont * myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gill Sans" size:19];
    CGSize textSize = [@"your text" sizeWithFont: myFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textFiled.frame.size.width, textFiled.frame.size.height) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    NSlog(@"this is your text size W=%f H=%f",textSize.width, textSize.height);`

Comment: I did, but that alone does not get me the result I want as described above.