# How to access individual lines in a UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview

How can you access specific lines of a `UITextView`? If the text view is 10 lines long and I wanted to change the style properties of the first two lines how could I do that?

Response to duplicate mark: Question is not a duplicate. Moderator you directed to an Objective-C tag.

Comment: Is it one continuous string that wraps or are the 10 lines separates by new lines?

Comment: One consecutive string.

Comment: @lucianomarisi Even if I could just access the index of the first and last characters on a line I think I could use `NSAttributedString` to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: @matt What you pointed to is obj-c, not Swift

Comment: That's as may be, but you can surely translate. Don't let a little thing like language stop you. The point is, that's how you find where the line wraps - you use the NSLayoutManager.

Comment: @matt it has been 2 years since, I needed this, and I need it in Swift. Please think more long term. 100s more people will need this answer in swift over the coming years.

Comment: @demiculus i have added a swift translation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56964242/10708998

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the UITextView content while user is typing you have to call `func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool`. Here you can take care of what user is typing.

Then to access a particular line you can call the code you see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188363/getting-the-text-of-a-particular-line-on-uitextview) and then .

Comment: I wrote the wrong thing. I am using a UITextView. Do you know how to do it with a text view?

Comment: My issue is that I'm not trying to handle user interaction. I'm trying to style text as it's put into the container. I want to make the first three lines a certain color, the next three lines a certain color, and so on.